# Views list content from different content types

Tags: 7, views

View is setup to list content from content type B and C.

Content B has title, image and date field.
Content C has title and date field, and i want to pull image field from content creator.

When users creates content type A which is mandatory after registering (B and C can not be created before A), image field is mandatory and it is possible to upload only 1 image in each of those (A, B and C).

How can i pull image field from A (for C), while listing B and C ?

Comment: How did you implement that "***B and C can not be created before A***"? Like do you have some special validation somewhere? Or maybe some other field in A,B or C that "connects" them?

Comment: Role 1 can only create A, after which he is given Role 2 in which can not create anymore A, and can only create B and C, while the image in A is mandatory.

Comment: Using Rules he gets Role 2 after saving content A.